# What does this recursive function do? And what is the runtime complexity?

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm confused on the following code. So far, I think it will return the smallest integer in the array with n elements. However, how does the recursion work? And, what is the runtime complexity of this function?

```
int fun(int arr[], int n)
{
    int x;
    if (n == 1)
        return arr[0];
    else
        x = fun(arr, n - 1);

    if (x <= arr[n - 1])
        return x;
    else
        return arr[n - 1];
}
```

Comment: Knowing what you know about the rules of C++, work through the function on paper with a few small lists of numbers and keep notes. To figure out the time complexity you need to determine how many times each element in the array is visited.

Comment: @user13717125 The function can invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Expanding on Vlad's comment with a simple example: Call `fun` with a list of size 0. The results will be... interesting.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed an odd looking function, but we can transform it to a more familiar form, a more classical recursive function.

First let's do some renaming. `n` is clearly the length of the array so we rename `n` to `size`. You assume `fun` is finding the minimum value in the array so let's start with this assumption and rename the function `fun`. In the end we will see if the assumption is correct or not.

Since on the `then` branch of `if` we have a `return` we can ditch the `else`. And we move the `x` declaration to the point of first use:

```
int arr_min(int* arr, int size)
{
    if (size == 1)
        return arr[0];

    int x = arr_min(arr, size - 1);

    if (x <= arr[size - 1])
        return x;
    else
        return arr[size - 1];
}
```

Now we clearly see the recursion end condition: `n==1` in which case we just return the only element of the array.

Next let's focus on the `if/else`. We can see that here the function returns the minimum between `x` and `arr[n-1]` so let's just write that:

```
int arr_min(int* arr, int size)
{
    if (size == 1)
        return arr[0];

    int x = arr_min(arr, size - 1);

    return std::min(x, arr[size - 1]);
}
```

Since now we read `x` only once, we can get rid of this badly named variable:

```
int arr_min(int* arr, int size)
{
    if (size == 1)
        return arr[0];

    return std::min(arr_min(arr, size - 1), arr[size - 1]);
}
```

This is an equivalent function with what you have, but is has a more "classical" recursive form. It's easier now to see that indeed the function returns the minimum element of an array:

The minimum element of an non-empty array is:

- if the array is of size 1: the first and only element
- else: it's minimum between:

  - the last element and
  - minimum element of the subarray that doesn't contain the last element

Now it's also easy to see the time complexity. I'll leave it to you to figure it out.

---

*note:* It should be obvious by now that the function is only defined for arrays with at least one element.

---

As a bonus I would like to rewrite this function in modern C++:

```
constexpr int arr_min(std::span<const int> arr)
{
    if (arr.size() == 1)
        return arr.front();

    auto head = arr.first(arr.size() - 1);
    return std::min(arr_min(head), arr.back());
}
```

And in a future standard near you:

```
constexpr int arr_min(std::span<const int> arr)
    [[assert: !arr.empty()]]
{
    if (arr.size() == 1)
        return arr.front();

    auto head = arr.first(arr.size() - 1);
    return std::min(arr_min(head), arr.back());
}
```